# The number of possible extensions of an embedding of a field into a algebraically closed field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I've been thinking this more than a week. My problem is the second part of the
Propositon 2.7. in *Algebra* by Serge Lang.

In the proposition, k is a field and $\sigma:k \rightarrow L$ is an embedding of $k$ into an algebraically closed field $L$. $\alpha$ is algebraic over $k$ and $p(X) \in k[X]$ is the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k$. $k^a$ is the algebraic closure of $k$.

> Proposition 2.7.
>   The number of possible extensions of $\sigma$ to $k(\alpha)$ is $\leq \deg p$, and is equal to the number of distinct roots of $p$ in $k^a$.

I understand that the number of possible extensions of $\sigma$ is equal to the number of distinct roots of $p^\sigma$ in $L$. But why is it equal to the number of distinct roots of $p$ in $k^a$?

Comment: $k^a$ embeds in $L$ since $L$ is algebraically closed and contains $k$, and $k^a$ is minimal. Hence the number of distinct roots are the same when viewed either in $k^a$ or $L$. (Is there some complexity I'm missing?)

Comment: @J Swanson. I think your argument is not acceptable, because the proposition Aki is asking about is logically prior to the existence of an embedding of $k^a$ in $L$.

Comment: Apply the first part of the proposition to the embedding $k\to k^\alpha$.

Comment: What edition are you reading?

Comment: The edition is revised third.

Comment: @user121926 But the OP said the number of extensions is the number of distinct roots of $p^\sigma$ in $L$, which is at least 1, so existence has been done.

Comment: @J Swanson. Perhaps for extensions generated by one element. But at that stage in Lang the theorem you're referring to hasn't been proved.

Comment: In Theorem 2.8. the existence of an extension of $\sigma$ to an embedding of arbitrary algebraic extension of $k$ is proved by using Proposition 2.7.

Comment: @user121926 Ah, I misparsed $k(\alpha)$ as $k^a$ last night, my apologies. Still, a straightforward Zorn's lemma argument amplifies the result to $k^a$. I've written the details in an answer. They're longer than I would wish considering how standard the argument is.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comments, here's an answer without Lang (which I don't have). I'll assume what you've already said, that the number of extensions of $\sigma \colon k \to L$ to $k(\alpha) \to L$ is the number of distinct roots of $p^\sigma$ in $L$ ($k$ any field, $\alpha$ algebraic over $k$, $L$ algebraically closed, all maps are embeddings of fields).

Proposition: An embedding $\sigma \colon k \to L$ into an algebraically closed field extends to an embedding $\mu \colon k^a \to L$ of the algebraic closure. $k^a/k$ is algebraic.

Proof: Standard Zorn. Let $S = \{\rho \colon K \to L : \rho|_k = \sigma,\ k \subset K \subset k^a, K/k\ {\rm algebraic}\} \neq \varnothing$. Partially order $S$ by "extension of". A non-empty totally ordered subset of $S$, $\{\rho_i \colon K_i \to L\}$, has an upper bound in $S$, as follows. Set $K = \cup_i K_i$, which is a field, and define $\rho \colon K \to L$ by $\rho|_{K_i} = \rho_i$, which is well-defined by the total order property, and $\rho \in S$. By Zorn's lemma, we have a maximal element $\mu \colon K \to L$ of $S$. If $K$ is not algebraically closed, we can find $\alpha$ algebraic over $K$, hence over $k$, not in $K$, so we can take $\alpha \in k^a - K$. But then the result you've said implies we can extend $\mu$ to $K(\alpha) \to L$ since there is at least one root of $p^\mu$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ viewed in $L$. Hence $K$ is algebraically closed, and from the minimality of the algebraic closure, $k^a = K$, and we've found our extension. $K=k^a$ was algebraic by construction, which is just a nice side note. $\Box$

Now the rest is easy. The number of distinct roots of $p^\sigma$ in $L$ is the number of distinct roots of $p$ in $k^a$ because $\mu$ gives a bijection between them.

Comment: This is exactly what is shown in Theorem 2.8. There is the following sentence imediately after the Proposition 2.7.: _This is an important fact, which we shall analyse more closely later_. Does this mean that the second part of the proposition will become clear later ? Or, is there other way to prove it ?

Comment: @Aki Your quote probably just refers to the actual count being  a relatively important fact in general. I doubt Lang is suggesting he'll present another proof later, but again I don't have the book. I consider the argument I gave both illuminating and straightforward. Logically isn't not important that it's apparently Theorem 2.8. Given your fragment of 2.7, my argument proves both Theorem 2.8 and the rest of 2.7 (and shows algebraic closures are algebraic for free). Does this answer your question satisfactorily?

Comment: Your argument is clear. I understand that the second part of the proposition is proved in that way. Do you think that it is impossible to prove it without using the extension of $\sigma$ to an embedding of $k^a$ in $L$ ?

Comment: @Aki "Morally" all you need is an embedding of the splitting field of $p$ over $k$ in $L$. For that just iteratively extend the embedding $k \to L$, $k(\alpha_1) \to L$, $k(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \to L$, ..., where $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $p$ in the splitting field. Since the splitting field embeds in both $L$ and $k^a$ (same argument), this gives a bijection between the two sets of roots. I didn't do this originally because I was following up on my initial comment.

Comment: Sorry for my repeated questions. When you extend the embedding $k(\alpha_1)\rightarrow L$ to $k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\rightarrow L$, you have to find another root of $p^\sigma$ in $L$. Is this always possible ?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. Let $S = k(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ be a splitting field for $p$ over $k$, which exists as usual. We can take $S \subset k^a$. $S$ need not be in $L$; you don't have to find roots of $p^\sigma$ in $L$ to find the $\alpha_i$'s--they exist independent of $L$. We just need need an embedding $\mu \colon S \to L$ extending $\sigma$, which you can get inductively. You can use $\mu$ to give a bijection between the roots of $p$ in $k^a$ and the roots of $p^\sigma$ in $L$.

Comment: It seems to me that to construct the embedding $\mu$ you need the same number of distinct roots of $p^\sigma(t)$ in $L$ as $p(t)$ in $k^a$. But that is what we want to prove in the first place.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying, but I don't think I can be clearer, sorry. This method is not circular.

Comment: When you extend $k(\alpha_1)\rightarrow L$ to $k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\rightarrow L$, you have to choose the destination of $\alpha_2$. If $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$, that must be different from $\beta_1$.

Comment: What is $\beta_1$? The destination of $\alpha_2$ is irrelevant, we just need to make some choice. The $\alpha_i$ don't *have* to be roots of $p$ anyway, they just need to generate the splitting field. I don't understand your objection. Throughout we just need that the minimal polynomial of the element we're adjoining when viewed in $L$ has at least one root in $L$, which it must trivially, and then we can apply the fragment of your result I quoted in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I assumed that $\beta_1$ is the destination of $\alpha_1$. If $\tau_2:k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\rightarrow L$ is the extension of $\tau_1:k(\alpha_1)\rightarrow L$.

Comment: I'm sorry again. I failed to post the previous comment.  If $p(t) \in k[t]$ is the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha_1$ and $\tau_1:k(\alpha_1)\rightarrow L$ is the extension of $\sigma$, and $\tau_2:k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\rightarrow L$ is the extension of $\tau_1$, then the destination of $\alpha_2$ must be a root of $p^\sigma$. For $0=\tau_2(p(\alpha_2))=p^\sigma(\tau_2(\alpha_2))$.

Comment: Is there an actual objection or are you just confirming your reasoning? If $\alpha_2$ is chosen to be a root of $p(t)$, then indeed "$\beta_2$" must be a root of $p^\sigma$ as well. It just doesn't seem important.

Comment: In your second comment after your answer, you mentioned that $\alpha_i$'s are roots of $p(t)$. If they are not, how do you construct the extension of $\sigma$ to the splitting field for $p(t)$ over $k$ ?

Comment: I said later they don't *have* to be roots of the polynomial; that's just the obvious choice, which is what I went with originally. For instance, if the splitting field has a primitive element, you could use that as $\alpha_1$ and be done in one step. My point is the roots you're adjoining might have little to do with the original polynomial $p$, so concerns about $p^\sigma$ when creating this extension of $\sigma$ are as a rule unfounded.

Comment: It seems that your argument is based on the existence of the extension proved by using Zorn's lemma. It is right. But, the proposition I asked about is logically prior to the existence of an embedding of algebraic extension of $k$ in L as user121926 pointed out. That's why I was interested in your second comment, because it seemed you suggested a constructive way to prove the second part of the proposition. I have no objection to your suggestion. I only wanted the explanation that process can be completed successfully. I've come up with the explanation. I post it the next comment.

Comment: After $\alpha_{k+1}$ a root of $f(t)$ is adjoined to $F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k)$,and the extension $\sigma_{k+1}$ of $\sigma:F \rightarrow L$ to $F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k,\alpha_{k+1})$ is obtained.$f(t)$ splits off a new factor $(x-\alpha_{k+1})^m$ in $F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k,\alpha_{k+1})$.
At the same time $\sigma_{k+1}f$ splits off a new factor $(x-\beta_{k+1})^n$ in $\sigma_{k+1}(F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k,\alpha_{k+1}))$, where $\beta_{k+1}=\sigma_{k+1}(\alpha_{k+1})$. We can prove that $n=m$ (continues to next comment)

Comment: We can prove that $n=m$ 
by utilizing the isomorphism of  $F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k,\alpha_{k+1})[t]$ and
$\sigma_{k+1}(F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k,\alpha_{k+1}))[t]$, 
since the latter is a uniquely factrizable domain.

Comment: Just to be completely clear, throughout I've been using the statement "the number of possible extensions of $\sigma$ is equal to the number of distinct roots of $p^\sigma$ in $L$" (and in particular is $\geq 1$) freely, which you said in your first post you understood/could prove/have a proof for. user121926 pointed out the need for an embedding $k^a \to L$, not $k(\alpha) \to L$, which I proved using Zorn. If you're happy, great.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to address the several comments and, of course, the OP's question:

First, in prop. 2.7, the algebraic closure $\;k^a\;$ isn't even mentioned so I'm not sure what's the problem here.

Second, in prop. 2.3 was already mentioned that upon having an embedding of fields $\;\sigma: k\to L\;$ we can then consider $\;k\;$ as a subfield of $\;L\;$ so that we can drop the annoying $\;k^\sigma\;$ notation .

Third, the existence of an algebraic closure was *already* established in Corollary 2.6.

Fourth: with all the above, talking of a root $\;\beta\in k^\sigma\;$ of $\;p^\sigma(x)=Irr(\alpha,k,x)^\sigma\;$ or of a(nother) root $\;\beta\;$ of $\;p(x)\;$ in $\;k\;$ is just "the same" (up to the embedding, of course).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 4th part ?

Comment: @Aki, if we identify $\;k\;$ with $\;k^\sigma\;$ and thus $\;p^\alpha(x)\;$ with $\;p(x)\;$ , then talking of roots in $\;k^\sigma\;$ or in $\;k\;$ of $\;p(x)\;$ or of $\;p^\sigma(x)\;$ is just the same.